# How to add clustered markers to a group [Here Maps api]

Tags: javascript, mapping, here-api

I want to hide specific markers on checkbox click, that's why i tried to 
add these markers to groups. But when i do this iconsGroup.getObjects();
it returns an empty array. What am i doing wrong ?

```
  var iconsGroup = new H.map.Group();
  var CUSTOM_THEME = {
           getClusterPresentation : function (cluster) {
                 var randomDataPoint = getRandomDataPoint(cluster),
                  bubbleContent = getBubbleContent(cluster);
                  // Get a reference to data object that DataPoint holds
                 map.setCenter(cluster.getPosition());
                   data = randomDataPoint.getData();
                var marker =  new H.map.DomMarker(cluster.getPosition(), {
                    icon: data.icon,
                    min: cluster.getMinZoom(),
                    max: cluster.getMaxZoom()

                  });
                iconsGroup.addObject(marker);
                marker.setData(bubbleContent);
                marker.addEventListener('tap', onClusterClick);
                return marker;
            },
            getNoisePresentation : function (noisePoint) {
              var data = noisePoint.getData();
              var noiseMarker = new H.map.DomMarker(noisePoint.getPosition(), {
                    icon: noisePoint.getData().icon,
                    min: noisePoint.getMinZoom()
                  });
              noiseMarker.setData(data);
              noiseMarker.addEventListener('tap', onMarkerClick);
              return noiseMarker;
            }
          }


      var clusterProvider = new H.clustering.Provider(arr, {
          clusteringOptions: {
           minWeight: 1,
           eps: 32
          }
        });
     clusterProvider.setTheme(CUSTOM_THEME);
    clusteringProviderArray.push(clusterProvider);
    var clusterLayer = new H.map.layer.ObjectLayer(clusterProvider);
    map.addLayer(clusterLayer);
 clusteringLayerArray.push(clusterLayer);
    groupLayers.push(iconsGroup);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will just use arrays instead of groups

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? If yes, How can we make clusters with groups ?